# VHDL - ror and rol operations

Tags: syntax, vhdl, xilinx

How can I solve this problem?
 reg variable is defined as:

```
 signal reg:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0):="00000001";
```

There is a problem with ror operation in the code below. The error message is:

```
Line 109: Syntax error near "ror".

Line 108: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
```

--

```
  process(clk1,up_down,enable,reset)
        begin
        if up_down="1" then
            reg ror 1;
        end if;
        end process;
```

Comment: What is the type of up_down? The string literal "1" is not of that type.  For each type declaration other than file and protected types there's an equality ("=") and inequality operator "/=" defined. A string literal's type is from context and must be a single dimensional array type with character enumeration elements (such as string, std_ulogic_vector, etc). Without a [mcve] a fix isn't apparent for the line 108 error.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the the `ror` operator is not defined for `std_logic_vector`.

VHDL exhibits a behaviour of computer (and hardware description) languages called *overloading*. Overloading is where an operator, function or procedure is multiply defined for different types. The compiler looks at the combination of types when the operator (etc) is used (called the *signature*) and tries it match that with the various versions that have been declared. This only works if there is exactly one match. Any more and the code is ambiguous, because the compiler doesn't know which version to used. Any less and there is no version for the compiler to use. This is your problem - there is no version of the `ror` operator that uses `std_logic_vector`.

You have two solutions:

(i) RECOMMENDED : implement your *rotate right* behaviour manually using the *concatenation* operator and *slicing*:

```
    if up_down="1" then
        reg <= reg(0) & reg(7 downto 1);
    end if;
```

(ii) NOT RECOMMENDED : convert your `std_logic_vector` to a different type that does have a version of the `ror` operator defined, eg `unsigned`. Why "not recommended"? Because I would not recommend using any the the following operators ever, because they can behave strangely (and their behaviour doesn't seem to be consistent across different EDA tools);

```
ror rol sla sra sll srl
```

---

By the way, this line would be wrong even if `ror` were defined for `std_logic_vector`:

```
reg ror 1;
```

You can't just say that any more than you could just say

```
reg + 1;
```

You need to assign the result of the operation in both cases to something. I have *assumed* you want to assign it to `reg` in both cases.

Comment: The corresponding sequence of statements is executed for a condition returning TRUE in an if statement.  `reg ror 1` is a shift expression not a sequential statement (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.8 If statement, 9. Expressions, 9.1 shift_expression, 9.2.4 Shift operators, 10. Sequential statements). Without knowing the type of up_down you can tell "1" isn't of that type. The equality operator (9.2.3 Relational operators) is defined for all types other than file and protected types. The type of a string literal is determined by context and shall be a single dimensional array type (9.3.2 Literals).