# VHDL : how to use rem and mod command in VHDL ? (syntax problem)

Tags: syntax, vhdl

hello I want to take the binary number of 23. and in binary form it is :  010111

so if for example 23 mod 10 i will get 3 . how to do this comand in VHDL ? this is what I wrote so far :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY rem_command IS
  GENERIC (display_resolution : INTEGER :=23;   -- counter to get to the loest ferquncy 
  display_counter: INTEGER :=8);        -- counter to get to 97KHz ferquincy 

PORT (
    CLK_IN :IN STD_LOGIC;
    PWM_LIMIT :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter downto 0);
    COUNTER_VECTOR :IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter downto 0);
    number_out: OUT  STD_LOGIC 
    );
END rem_command;

ARCHITECTURE testing_reminder_command  OF  rem_command  I
    signal number : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0):="010111"; -- this is 23 in binary form 
BEGIN
        process(COUNTER_VECTOR,PWM_LIMIT,CLK_IN,number)
        BEGIN
                number <= 10 MOD number;                                                
        end process;

    number_out<=number;

END testing_reminder_command ;
```

the error that I get is :

> Error (10327): VHDL error at rem_command.vhd(48): can't determine
>   definition of operator ""mod"" -- found 0 possible definitions

maybe I need to add library ?

Comment: You need to read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389379/vhdl-ror-and-rol-operations) .

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how can it help my problem

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same: the `mod` and `rem` operators are not defined for `std_logic_vector`. You need to use a different type, for which they are defined, for example `unsigned`. Basically, never use the `std_logic_vector` type for doing maths. It is not intended for that. If you're new to the `unsigned` type and _type conversions_, then have a look at [these examples](https://www.edaplayground.com/playgrounds?searchString=numeric&language=VHDL&simulator=&methodologies=&_libraries=on&_easierUVM=on&curated=true&_curated=on&_csrf=57c8773e-9d90-41a9-be00-75f77cf5c823).

Comment: You'll find with number declared as type unsigned the assignment to number_out fails. number_out is type std_logic (and should be either std_logic_vector or unsigned with a matching element for each element of number, checked during signal update in simulation). If number_out is std_logic_vector (5 downto 0) then number must be be converted - `number_out <= std_logic_vector(number);` Type unsigned and std_logic_vector are closely related allowing type conversion, both having the same element base type (std_ulogic) and both single dimensional array types. THEN the code will analyze (compile).

Comment: NOW comes a nasty part. `number <= 10 mod number;` with number in the process sensitivity list causes recursion, where eventually you'll divide by 0 during simulation, "DIV, MOD, or REM by zero" an error. The proper thing would be to merge the assignment of number_out - `number_out <= std_logic_vector( 10 mod number);` presumably in the process. These two comments presume using package numeric_std.

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely wanted to use the "mod" and "rem" operators:

- They are not defined in any of the packages that you are using.
- FIX: **use ieee.numeric_std.all** package
- **mod** and **rem** don't operate on **std_logic_vector**. So, you need to implement *type conversions* on your **std_logic_vector** signals

Comment: `mod `and `rem `operate on `unsigned` and `signed` types, too.

Comment: I added the use iee.numeric_std.all package but now I get other error :    signal number : unsigned(5 downto 0):="010111"; -- this is 23 in binary form

Comment: That sounds like you need to ask another question.

Comment: You cannot reference both numeric_std and std_logic_arith and then use "unsigned" as a simple name.   The easy solution is to remove std_logic_arith as it is an older open source package that is not an IEEE standard and should have never been in the IEEE library - likewise for std_logic_unsigned.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor   Actually the OPs follow on question is because the proposed FIX is incomplete - it should have been delete std_logic_arith and replace it with numeric_std.